# Can a Thai national married to a UK citizen enter the UK freely?

Tags: visas, eu, family, eu-citizens, thai-citizens

I am a UK Citizen/Passport Holder, have a house in the UK but have been mainly in Thailand for the past twelve months, so currently deemed a nonresident in the UK.

The reason for being in Thailand is that I got married to a Thai lady, (Thai Passport).  All registered and legalized at the British Embassy in Bangkok.

Now, I also have a house in France, and we want to go there for a second time next month on a Schengen Visa (free, pretty automatic).  We do not plan to go back to Thailand.

We have applied for my wife to be issued with a French Resident card (Carte de Sejour), which means she can travel freely between EU countries and Thailand.

**My question is**:   Does the fact that she is married to an EU Citizen allow her to freely visit the UK?  Or does she still have to apply for a Visitor Visa?  In Practice, we want to spend three months at a time in UK/France/UK/France etc until we decide exactly where we live - probably moving back to the UK.

Hedging our options we have also applied in Thailand for a UK Settlement Visa for my wife.

Comment: Why not call the British Embassy in Bangkok and ask?  They would have the answers.

Comment: Impossible to get anyone to answer the telephone and they do not respond to emails.

Comment: @GregHewgill UK uses different criteria as opposed to EU. So the link you posted might not be the answer to OPs question.

Comment: @GregHewgill, this is not a duplicate.  The UK visa system does not participate in the EU's visa system.  Please retract any close votes.

Comment: Graham .. my advice .. take the opportunity to move to france once and for all :/

Answer (score 6):

If you never lived elsewhere in the EU, EU law has no bearing on the matter and regular UK law applies. Being married to a UK citizen is not enough to enter the country and your wife will need a visitor visa to enter the UK on a visit and a [‘family of settled person’ visa](https://www.gov.uk/join-family-in-uk) to move there.

If you live in France and your wife has a *carte de séjour “membre de la famille d'un citoyen de l'Union”* (EU family member’s residence card), she should in principle be able to enter the UK with it [*if you are traveling together*](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/index_en.htm). For a long time, the UK refused to fully implement the relevant EU directive but following a decision by the [EU Court of Justice](http://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2014/dec/18/non-eu-family-members-visa-uk-european-court), it relented and issued [new guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card) that you may be able to use. She might still need a different visa to enter the UK on her own.

Furthermore, a French *carte de séjour* does not entitle you to live anywhere else in the EU than France but once you have lived in France, the Singh ruling would kick in and you could also use that to settle in the UK.

In practice, I don't think that having used several Schengen visas or owning an house helps by itself (although people have tried to argue things like that in court), it's best to *reside* in France for a few months, either as a worker or as a non-economically active person. I am not quite sure of the type of documentation you need to show UK authorities to convince them that you did in fact use your treaty rights but paying income tax or holding a French *carte de séjour* seem like things that would help.

Whether you want to visit the UK under EU rules or use the Singh ruling to establish residency, it would therefore seem useful to first stay in France long enough to get a proper *carte de séjour* (possibly 6 months or so) instead of going back-and-forth on short-term visas.

Since [the whole thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surinder_Singh_route) is rather complex and your future life in the UK is potentially at stake, hiring a solicitor familiar with such matters is a good idea if you can afford it.

Comment: Relaxed, do you have any official documents that allow the part "if and only if you are traveling together"? Because Ireland stated officially this right in their current Immigration Act (http://www.irishstatutebook.ie/pdf/2012/en.si.2012.0417.pdf Page 4 comma C), but as far as I know UK never stated this right officially

Comment: @GuidePreite It's EU law but I must admit I am not sure of its implementation status. If it's not implemented, I would expect the Court of Justice to force the UK to do it at some point but that would not be very helpful to the OP for the time being. The UK is certainly not required to grant entry to non-EU family members who travel alone.

Comment: @GuidePreite It seems the UK does not recognize this right at the present time. As could be expected, there is a case in front of the EUCJ and the [advocate-general issued an opinion condemning this interpretation](http://europa.eu/rapid/press-release_CJE-14-75_en.htm) but the case hasn't been decided yet.

Comment: afaik UK still requires to ask for the EEA family permit (free in this case) but I have no personal experience on this scenario

Comment: @GuidePreite Yes, it seems you are correct. The bit about traveling alone vs. traveling together comes from the [Commission's interpretation of the applicable law](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/index_en.htm). I edited the answer to clarify that/correct the mistake.

Comment: Above seems to sum it up very well.  We Would of course be travelling together.

Comment: I hope this situation will be fixed soon, the EEA family permit is free, but the family member still need to go to the appointment in person, in some cases is more convenient to ask for a 5/10 year (expensive) visa than go & back to the visa center for several free EEA family permit.

Comment: It's the "should in principle be able to enter the UK" that makes it dubious.  Does the partner need to be employed? What's the success rate for this type of entry: "should in principle"?

Comment: @GayotFow “should” in the sense that it's what EU law mandate (as far as I, the EU Commission and the authorities of most other EU countries understand it) but the success rate would seem to be very low indeed, as the UK does not agree with this interpretation as I just learned. We'll have to wait for the CJEU to settle this difference. In countries where the rule does apply, the partner does not need to be employed (but that's one of several ways to qualify for an EU family member's residence card in the first place).

Comment: I would suggest that anyone using this answer to plot an immigration strategy (visit or residence) should seriously consider consulting a professional and accredited solicitor beforehand.

Comment: @GayotFow +1 to your comment, I will edit my answer to highlight it. That's a good point in any case, especially for people who ultimately want to move to the UK.

Comment: @Relaxed, per Joe Blow's comment, would you also open a question about the phone menus and what can be done when somebody doesn't know how to proceed?  Citing what a disaster they are.  Scope it to SETTLEMENT only.

Comment: @Relaxed there is an update about this: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card but the problem can be if police border is able to recognize a right residence permit in this scenario

Comment: for example, the Italian residence permit released for the 2004/38/EC directive is an A4 paper with no direct references to 2004/38/EC but onlt to the Italian law that implements that directive, a text "ART 10 D.LVO 30/07" under notes

Comment: @GuidoPreite Yes, indeed, it's an important point. But France does not issue anything else than common format residence permits except in some very specific cases (like people with an application for asylum pending) so I don't think it should be an obstacle in this particular case. I was also under the impression that all the older residence permits were to be phased out, does Italy still issue those A4 permits to EU citizens' spouses today?

Comment: yes, they still use the A4 format for EU citizens' spouses and family members

Comment: Regarding France I found this specimen http://www.imprimerienationale.fr/en/products-services/electronic-european-residence-permit.html, the notes section contains the family status

Comment: @GuidoPreite Yes, that's the right one. You can also see a full list of residence documents on [prado](http://prado.consilium.europa.eu/EN/categories/FRA/H/resultByCountryCategory.html). “Membre de famille de citoyen de l'UE” is the French version of the “Family Member of a Union Citizen” wording mentioned in the guidance.

Comment: As long as it's a common format article 10 document with the right wording, I should hope UK border guards have a table of translations at hand and do not insist on an *English-language version* of the mention because that would seem difficult to reconcile with EU law and practice.

Answer (score 5):

Caveat:  The Home Office has just published their report (dated Summer 2014) called *Review of the Balance of Competences between the United Kingdom and the European Union Single Market: Free Movement of Persons* which may (or may not) affect policy decisions impacting your question.  Not immediately, but possibly in the foreseeable future.

The UK is generally reluctant to honour a French residence permit because the holder is married to *you* who is a Brit. The UK does not participate in EU residence and/or the Schengen programme.   She can apply for a UK visitor visa, and the chances of success are 'iffy' because she's clearly an overstay risk given that you have a home in the UK.  Of course, she's entitled to apply, but be aware of the risks.

Two options.  The first is what you're already doing: apply for a spouse visa.  This lets her come and go for 30 months and it's renewable for another 30 months.  After 60 months she can apply for Indefinite Leave (ILR).

The other option is to try the Singh loophole after you have been living with her in France for 6 months.  It's a gamble, but if she gets it, it's cost free from there on.

Calling the British Consulate for advice is a waste of time.  You will enter a telephone maze of recordings and circular menu options.  Consular staff are forbidden (since about 2008) to discuss it with individuals in the first instance.  They will route you to their 3rd party contractor who will (astonishingly) charge you by the minute to read their web site to you over the phone.

A BBC article describing the Singh loophole is here: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-23029195

### Adding 27 Feb 2016

Before using the Singh loophole it's wise to consider what may happen if the UK leaves the EU.  There is a *possibility* that those residing in the UK who used Singh may find themselves with a precarious immigration status. The policy has not been drafted, so it is only something to consider. Maybe a tranche of migrants will be required to apply for indefinite leave or maybe they won't. It cannot be predicted and at this point in time it's prudent to consider all the various outcomes.  In the event the UK opts out of the EU, they wouldn't get around to even drafting the policy until about 2018 and it would include a transition arrangement anyway.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47420/discussion-on-answer-by-gayot-fow-can-a-thai-national-married-to-a-uk-citizen-en).