# How soon can I re-apply for a UK visa after getting a refusal?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, j1-visas, nigerian-citizens

I am from Nigeria and I'm doing a one year Internship program with The Marriott hotel in Wisconsin, I applied for the UK visitor visa two weeks ago to visit my fiance who lives and work in the UK, but I was refused the visa because the letter of my workplace that I provided was back dated of 2014 which they say they are not satisfy it accurately reflects my current employment circumstance. I also provided my pay slips, but they said they were not satisfied with it demonstrating the terms and conditions of my employment, and they also said I did not present any evidence to satisfy me having sufficiently strong ties and commitments in my country of habitual residence or elsewhere to motivate my timely departure from the UK. They said the documents my fiance presented were OK.

How soon can I re-apply for a UK visa after getting a refusal?

Comment: Can you edit this question to have more detail and clarity? You've tagged it [tag:j1-visas], but that's a US visa and you're applying for the UK you say, but the hotel in Wisconsin is in the US...it's very confusing.
It's highly important to be very clear in these matters, this may also be why applications get rejected at times.

Comment: @MarkMayo: It looks like the OP is **from** Nigeria, but **currently** living in the US on a one-year J-1 program which started at some time in 2014. She wants to **visit** the UK. Based on that it doesn't seem strange that the British authorities doesn't think she has sufficient ties to the US to return there after her UK visit -- after all the ties she has to show is an internship (which is either unpaid or not highly paid) which is time limited and will run out in at most half a year from now, at which point she'll be out of status in the US too.

Comment: From the point of view of a British consular officer, this will certainly look like you're in a situation where you'll have a lot of motivation to stay illegally in the UK living with your fiance, and not much motivation to leave the UK (except perhaps for a general desire to follow the law, which consular officers cannot afford to assume of applicants). So even if they **believe** everything you've told about your situation in the US, they probably won't let you in. You'll have to wait until you live somewhere that you have stronger and more permanent ties to.

Answer (score 5):

As I understand it you want to know how long you have to wait to make a fresh application following the refusal of a visitor visa application.  You mentioned that they gave multiple reasons for the refusal, but the only apparent question is the interval ('how long...').

There is no set interval required between successive applications. You can apply again immediately if you want.  Many people do this when the refusal is simple enough to fix, like they submitted the wrong bank statement or forgot to include their employment contract.

Based on what you wrote, you would need to spend some time to prepare a more convincing set of evidence.  You did not include the text of your refusal notice, so I cannot be more specific.  You can read the guidance for visitor applications at https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/424265/VAF1-GUIDANCE-NOTES.pdf  The guidance was published only last week, so it's likely you haven't seen this version before.

---

**To summarize**: you can make a new application any time you want, even on the same day as your refusal. But note that if you apply with the same evidence they will refuse again and then matters will be worse.

NOTE: See also [How Long till I Reapply](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38487/uk-family-visa-refused-how-long-till-i-reapply?rq=1)