# My girlfriend was a refused a visa to visit me in the UK. What now?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, russian-citizens

I have read lots of stories about visa refusal and I'm no exception as I have just had my applicant denied too.

After reading refusal it is very common for the applicant to be refused because of a financial situation. As a sponsor it declared they see no reason the sponsor can fund my partner for her visit, but applicant had no funds and could not see her returning after her stay. So conclusion was they denied it on this. I could not appeal or get administration review and told be 12 months before we can apply again???

My partner's financial situation will not change, but as a sponsor I was giving all. I have sponsored her holidays over 18 months and paid for all, 
because it as been rejected now I will sponsor her holidays again this year too.

My question is this. I will re-apply for a visitors visa in 12 months but her financial situation will not have changed. How do I get the embassy to accept what I wrote to be true? I have no intentions of my partner overstaying— who is to say she likes the UK? If we decide in the future for a spouse visa, I will apply for one.
[image: Refusal letter 1]
[image: Refusal letter 2]

Comment: Just to clarify, are you the sponsor and a UK citizen?

Comment: uk citizen and sponsor ,

Comment: The refusal letter ,  baffles me , when i read about about a visitor who im sponsoring as stated by gov.uk , everything was perfect to the letter , the money-gram payments was gifts ,birthday, flight which was booked 17th august a medical payment for a lymph node injections and her agency and visa payment  December , not really a income , who would think it was ? also on mony=gram they said housekeeper written.she is a shopkeeper , i know she as no money , why i gave them all my financial details ,gov,uk sponsor , paragraph v4,3

Comment: @mart1004, great question, a few more details please, her approximate age and the approximate age gap between you and any previous travel history where you met in person.

Comment: Im 52 male and fem is 42 , 10years between us , we met july  2014 , then again october 2014 december 2014 , may 2015 and october 2015 , all in egypt , then the bomb  and now cannot why we opted for the visa

Answer (score 13):

We can take things from the top...

**i could not appeal or get administration review**

No, there is no path for appeal in visitor applications.  Administrative review is a process reserved for applicants in the tiered system, so it's irrelevant anyway. But there's clearly an ownership issue and they have picked up on it (it happens a lot), more about that later.

**12 months before we can apply again???**

This is not correct. A person can apply again as soon as they get their passport back from the VFS, even the same day.  There is no required interval between successive applications and you can find an existing answer here: [How soon can I re-apply for a UK visa after getting a refusal?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47080/how-long-can-i-reapply-uk-general-visa-after-refusal/47083#47083)

**how do i get the embassy to accept what i wrote to be true?**

They have not challenged your credibility. The ECO explains that she's OK on your side of things.  The age difference is also OK.  But *again* the ownership issue arises...

**i have no intentions of my partner overstaying**

This unveils a problem.  You do not own the applicant or the application, it's not your application, it's hers. You are a sponsor and your role is strictly limited to establishing your own credibility and providing the sponsor support documents.  You did that in a way that they are satisfied with, and to attempt going beyond the role of sponsor raises alarm bells for a decision-maker. Let's introduce two points that causes romantically motivated applications to fail...

1. A sponsor's responsibility is to demonstrate the capacity to
   maintain and accommodate the application.  Nothing else.  Your
   'intentions' are irrelevant and attempting to assert them indicates
   that you do not understand what your role is and by extension that
   you do not understand the rules.  This is a fair assumption on their
   part because if your friend decided to go underground and
   disappeared inside the UK there is nothing you could do to prevent
   it.
2. Even worse, you cannot attest to the applicant's intentions. The
   applicant is a different person and while you may be certain of her
   intentions, decision-makers do not accept that sort of thing.  The 
   ECO reminded your gf...

   > "...the onus is on you, the applicant, to demonstrate...

The ECO went on to explain that she is basically OK with your gf's 'spravka' (that's a *very* good thing) but it did not apparently jive with the other stuff your gf submitted (that's a bad thing). It's likely your gf has never applied before and did not know what was expected of her.

Finally, the ECO went on to explain that the pattern of your gifts (in the form of bank transfers)  suggested that your relationship was something like a kept woman who received maintenance payments from abroad.  Your gf should have declared this as additional income. Paradoxically, doing that would have helped the application. Again, this type of mistake happens a lot with romantically motivated visa applications.

So the ECO concluded that your gf was not a genuine applicant or did not understand what she was doing and the risk of her going underground was unacceptably high. V 4.2 (a) & (c).

She's probably devastated and you are probably angry, scouring the net for forum advice. They don't like having upset sponsors, it's not good for their image, but the application left them no choice apparently.  This is a fairly 'vanilla' type of refusal and you can engage a [regulated adviser](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/office-of-the-immigration-services-commissioner) to manage her next application. I am guessing this would cost about GBP 400 - 550 (but that's strictly a *guess*). You can print out [this question/answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62691/vistor-visa-refusal-from-russia-to-uk-what-now/62702#62702) along with the refusal notice and email it to an adviser and get a better estimate. A [full-on solicitor](https://www.lawsociety.org.uk/) can be used if you want, but isn't usually needed in these types of 'vanilla' cases; adviser versus solicitor is a matter of personal choice really.

Comment: Thankyou gayot . Your documentation gives me a better understanding . One thing . Applicant says they stamped her passport and cannot re apply ???

Comment: Ignore it. Many times it means that they want you to go for a fiance or spouse visa, if that's in scope then proceed accordingly.

Comment: I understand the process for a spouse visa . My g/f needs to learn English for this visa . Have you any knowledge of what they require . As it may be the next step . But a visit was what I wanted  . And proceed from there . Also the visor visa for 6 months can I be used twice in this time . And what percentage would think we have . As we are going to Cyprus in April now . But on return I will start again on the 2nd visa

Comment: @mart1004, it's not a forum here. You asked your question and you got your answer. You can wait for more answers or ask a new question or whatever. We cannot go along dragging it out with comments. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers  and note that spouse visa questions go on http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions