# 6-month UK visa from Russia refused. What to do?

Tags: visas, uk

*This is a follow-up from a [previous question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62691):*

My girlfriend had a 6-month visa for the UK, which expired in December. She reapplied last week, and this time it was denied. Mainly it seems because her employment has changed, and admittedly the sums she presented didn't tally up.

It seems now the best thing to do is wait 6 months because then her employment and payslips will look consistent (her employer is going to help with this).

So is this the best thing to do, wait 6 months and reapply for same type of visa? With me down as the sponsor (last time she put herself down to pay for the trip, then her mum, then my details, and it seems my details and letter were largely ignored).

It seems that doing the form by herself and trying to be honest and transparent created a problem.

She has a Schengen visa which lasts through until the summer, so seeing her won't be impossible, but the strain is going to be tremendous. I am a UK citizen with full-time employment, and apart from going to see her in Russia and quick and expensive trips in Europe, I just don't know what I can do to make sure I've explored all options and done the best I can.

Anything at all in terms of advice is appreciated, but I guess mainly, would it change if I put myself as sponsor and fill in myself? Should I definitely wait? Is there anything I can do to have her here sooner? Or at least to ensure same problems don't arise again? If we were to go down the route, is marrying abroad and then having her come through a spouse application the most fail-safe way?

Thank you so much to all.

[image: let 1]
[image: let 2]

Comment: "I feel I have rambled on" - yes. Please edit out the parts that don't relate directly to your question so that we can focus on exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Many thanks Airsick. I feel the context provided still probably helps, but will try to edit some out so as to benefit from all the valued help from you kind members.

Comment: If you have the opportunity to visit Russia go - it is a lovely country. BUT you'll be in trouble without Russian.... (OK, you will get by with English in Moscow and I guess St. Petersburg too - I have only been to Moscow twice and had some to introduce me to "important bits".) - With a local person to translate and guide you, it would provide excellent opportunities for discovering both the country and its culture.

Answer (score 5):

Every year, there are thousands of UK/RU refusals with the very same pattern as this, between British men and Russian women (whether crush, limerence or love). I communicated with [@GayotFow via his blog](https://gayotfow.wordpress.com/) and, in turn, he asked that I share his thoughts, as he’s far too ill at the moment to give more than fleeting comments.

Contrary to your understanding for the refusal, your girlfriend's premise should have been to maintain a relationship, out in the open and above board. Your role was to explain how you met, and each and every meeting since that time. You cannot and should not make attestations about her intentions to be compliant with the visa conditions. No one can know what a person will do, nor can anyone guarantee applicant compliance.

Your girlfriend already visited the UK recently, you don’t say for how long she was there, but almost immediately upon return to her home country, she wants to go back to the UK. And she offered no valid premise, not relationship, work, study, business. Her change of employment had little to do with the refusal: the documents she included did not substantiate claims she was making about where she worked, her income and expenses. It appeared that money may have been funneled into her bank account, ‘funds parking’ as used on this site and as coined by @GayotFow.

You will find a lot of this material is covered in [the TSE canonical](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e), particularly those sections which discuss maintaining a relationship, sponsorship, and funds parking.

With this refusal on her record, better that you visit her in either Russia or another country. If your intention is to marry, then review the [requisites for a family visa](https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/partner-spouse) to ensure you and she are well-informed and prepared for the process and documentation.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer and your advice. Indeed I had wanted to just sponsor her and put that as the premise, but because the first tourism visa route had worked with such ease, she had thought it better to try this again. As it stands, plan to see her in other countries and then in June re-apply gain, with me sponsoring her. Her documents would show continued employment there and I would sponsor her, making it likely we would be eligible for the 6 months? After that one, whether rejected or upon completion, the next step would be marriage. Worried from your advice this is bad idea?

Answer (score 2):

Beware that whatever you or your girlfriend do, she is unlikely to get a further 6-month visa. One 6-month visa is fairly easy to get. A second one is much harder. This is because it can lead to a claim that there is a protected (i.e. family) relationship between you. So if you wish to deepen the relationship, you may well find that you need to do so outside the UK. If you get to the stage of wanting to marry, she can then apply for a marriage visa to enable her to enter the UK. Provided you have sufficient income and can demonstrate that it is a genuine relationship, she is likely to get such a visa. But getting from where you are now to where you would like to be is likely to involve much separation and heartache.

Sorry I can't be more positive. I've seen this before.