# How to help someone from Turkey obtain a 3 week tourist visa to visit the UK with a letter of invitation

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, tourist-visas

I am inviting a friend from Turkey to visit me in Scotland this August/September and would like to know how to improve the chance of the visa being accepted.

The main sticking point is likely to be her own funds for the trip, which are not high (I believe around 400GBP - hopefully a bit more). However, it is a short trip (3 weeks) and I make clear in the letter that I am happy to meet any costs of the trip beyond her ability to pay.

My friend will have just graduated with a degree in industrial engineering. I hope that this might help to assuage fears that she has any other intention than tourism. Someone with a good STEM degree in Turkey has better career prospects that someone in the UK who is not allowed to be here.

Here is the invitation letter as it currently stands:

[image]

She spent a year in Spain on the Erasmus programme, and spent the  Christmas period in France and Holland, which I hope might help, as it demonstrates some travel history.

Does it help or hinder the application for me to offer to pay flights & insurance? (as I will) I have read that this is looked upon unfavourably. But if I leave it out, her own finances look even weaker.

How much of a long shot is this?

Are we being naive to even try to apply when she herself doesn't have great financial means? If the application is rejected, it could prejudice future applications to visit, which might be made when she is in a better financial situation.

If it is likely to fail, I would rather advise that she leave it for now. On the other hand, I feel the request is a reasonable one - and I don't think she should be put off if it has a chance of succeeding.

She has suggested I should go to the council so that it can be sent via them to the consulate in Istanbul. But I am not sure that's how things are done here. Shouldn't I just send directly to the consulate?

What evidence do I need to supply to demonstrate my financial situation? A bank statement and, say, most recent contract of my ltd company? (I am a contractor so don't have an employment contract). Should these be sent along with the letter?

I take it from Gayot Fow's response to [My girlfriend was a refused a visa to visit me in the UK. What now?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62691/my-girlfriend-was-a-refused-a-visa-to-visit-me-in-the-uk-what-now/62702#62702) that my role in her application is just to establish my ability and willingness to fully sponsor her. I think this part should be straightforward.

How much would seeking legal advice make a difference - and roughly how much might this cost?

There are several questions above but they come down to: how much can I do to help her application?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: There's no reason to involve the council unless you live in council housing, and the only thing you might need in that case is proof that you are allowed to have a guest for three weeks.

Comment: How is Aaaa's engineering degree relevant to Xxxx's visit to the UK? ;-)

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/what-details-should-a-good-cover-letter-contain-to-back-up-a-uk-visit-visa-appli If your earnings go through your limited company account you should provide personal & company bank statements, copies of contracts for say the last 6 months, and your most recent tax return.

Comment: Don't overthink or overdo it. Your letter provides the reason for the trip and part of the financing. You cannot assure anybody that the visitor will not overstay, that's what the visitor must do himself by presenting a convincing overall picture. You should clarify how much you spend and that you can easily afford it, and that your friend ist not a random stranger/scammer you met on the web.