# How long should I wait to reapply after refusal of Visa in UK?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

My mom & I applied for visit visa to attend my sisters wedding. She got hers approved but mine was denied. She needs to be accompanied bec she is old now. The consul said that I lack some documents & my stay in UK doesn't match my mom stay there. I plan to stay in UK for a month or less but mom wants to stay in UK for 1-3 months. I am planning to re-apply, should I also put that I will stay for 1-3 months like my mom? And I have the documents that they needed. I just got my visa refusal letter & passport yesterday. How long should I wait to re-apply? Will it take 3-6 months to re-apply? Thanks

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38487/uk-family-visa-refused-how-long-till-i-reapply

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/36755/1820